# automatic reference disable in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

How can i disable automatic reference for specific files in IOS.
I have a facebook API, where it isn't automatic reference and so I want to disable it for facebook api files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head to the compile sources section of the build phases and add the "-fno-objc-arc" to the files you want to disable ARC for.

[image]